# List interface: from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java, list, interface, generic-collections

I'm a Java programmer learning C# these days.

Usually in Java when using lists, it should be preferrable programming against its interface in order to switch between implementations:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
//or
list = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

What about C# ? Does exist a similar approach? Can someone show me an example? Since now I'm building a list this way, but I don't think List is an interface:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(2);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In .NET it is also preferable to work with the highest possible object in the hierarchy. You could use the [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) interface:

```
IList<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(2);
```

And if you don't need to access the list by index you could also use the [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) interface which is even higher in the hierarchy.

Or if you only want to enumerate through the list you could use the highest possible interface which is [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
foreach(int item in list)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<int> = new List<int>();
```

in C# it's easy - if it starts with an `I` its an interface.

Answer (score 1):

[`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) implements a number of interfaces, including [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) and [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx). You may need to examine your code to determine which interface is most appropriate.

Comment: thanks..could you explain the difference between IList and ICollection in a few words?

Comment: @Heisenbug - I linked to their documentation, and @Darin has already explained a key difference - that an `IList<T>` supports indexed access.

Answer (score 1):

In .net [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) is the interface. And you can assign it any of the interface's implementations e.g., [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). See the implementations of this interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx#inheritanceContinued